# How can I test method behaviour on not-existing interface implementation in Kotlin?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

Let suppose, I have an interface `Animal`, it has two implementations: `Dog` and `Cat`, and we have some method for this class:

```
fun Animal.sound() : String {
  if (this is Dog) return "woof"
  if (this is Cat) return "meow"
  return "globglogabgalab"
}
```

Then, I want to test all cases of this method

How can I do that (with JUnit/Mockito), if I don't have an implementation for default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use kotlins [Sealed classes in combination with a `when` statement](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html#sealed-classes-and-when-expression), then you wouldn't need the last return statement, because that would statement would be unreachable.

```kotlin
sealed class Animal
class Dog : Animal()
class Cat : Animal()
```

and the sound method would look like this.

```kotlin
fun Animal.sound() = when (this) {
  is Cat -> "meow"
  is Dog -> "woof"
}
```

Alternatively, without sealed classes you could just create a `TestAnimal` implementation, which implements `Animal` in your tests, then instantiate it and run the `sound()` method.

```
class TestAnimal : Animal

@Test
fun foo() {
  TestAnimal().sound()
}
```

or with a anonymous implementation

```
@Test
fun foo() {
  val animal = object : Animal {}

  animal.sound()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I probably didn't formulate the question very clearly - theoretically, someone else can add another implementation for `Animal`, for which the default behavior is suitable, but now there is no such implementation - I would like to test the default behavior

Comment: I updated my comment with an additional solution. I'm not sure if the syntax is correct as I did not test it, but you get the basic idea.